# What is the verb used to indicate that you have travelled from point A to B by motorboat?

Tags: verbs, single-word-requests, analogy

Please consider the following and fill in the blank.  This has driven me crazy ever since I moved to florida.  How would somebody say the travel often by a boat without any sails.

- I **drove** from New York to California.  <-- By Car
- I **flew** from New York to California. <-- By plane
- I **sailed** from New York to London. <-- by Sailboat
- I **blank** from New York to Florida <-- by motorboat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Sail** can be used to describe the generic act of traveling by water, regardless of whether the craft used actually has a sail for its propulsion or not.

Comment: I agree, this is probably the most acceptable; This does not give an appropriate visual image of the mode of transportation.  It's like driving somewhere and saying "I wheeled to the store", (bike,train,car,wagon, anything with wheels)

Comment: also, if I where to travel by some non-traditional; hot-air balloon. I would expect to have to say "I flew from NY to LA in a hot-air balloon". In the case of travelling by water, isn't motorized boat the traditional way in modern times?  Should it be expected that I say "I sailed from NY to LON by speedboat"

Comment: I wouldn't use sail for travelling by kayak (I would paddle) or row-boat (I would row)...

Comment: I'd go with "I took a speedboat from NY to London" (although that would be pretty noteworthy since speedboats are generally small pleasure craft used for trips measured in hours, not suited to week-long voyages).  For larger, commercial vehicles, you might say steamboat, passenger ship, or cruise ship.

Comment: @Doug: Must be one heck of a fuel tank on that speedboat... ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Motor-boated. It makes sense and is in the dictionary, first used way back in 1922.

Comment: does that mean `boated` is a verb?

Comment: _Boat_ is also a verb, and it means _to travel or go in a boat for pleasure_.

Comment: Could you just use motored?

Comment: One might go _boating_ on a _boating lake_; clearly the gerund and present participle must stem from the verb _boat_.

Comment: @HorusKol: In this context, not really; saying you _motored_ from A to B does not convey the information that the motor vehicle you used was a boat.

Comment: Not to spoil the party, but have you considered http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=motorboat? It's the first/second result when googling `motorboat` or `motor-boat`.

Comment: @HorusKol: “motored” usually means travelling by car (and is a bit old-fashioned, at that).

Comment: @Hello71: I don't even need to click that link to know what it refers to! My answer would be if you can't use the word 'motor-boat' without some of the more immature members of your audience sniggering then perhaps you should reconsider them as audience members!

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: What if I were travelling by submarine? I motor-subbed?

Comment: 'Submarine' is also a verb, so 'submarined' would be the past tense.

Answer (score 5):

Cruised is another common term.

Answer (score 1):

*Steamed* is the technical term, though *sailed* is more usual.

Comment: Yes, and ironically, sails are still widely used but steam is only used by a small number of hobbyists.

Comment: @mickeyf: ...and nuclear warships.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping I didn't miss this already but the correct answer is to "Pilot" a boat.  I Piloted the boat from point A to point B.

Comment: yeah, except if I'm the passenger and not the captain I don't think this would apply.

Answer (score 0):

I would say I **raced** to Florida by motorboat, or **cruised** if the trip was more leisurely.