# If I drive a car and ride a motorcycle, what do I do with a boat?

Tags: verbs, nouns

Once we have specific verbs to refer to the action of operating a vehicle, my question is:

What verb should I use to "drive" a boat/ship?

Comment: What *kind* of boat? This question has been asked before for [motorboats](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10828/) and [ferries](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118475/). The answer for a sailing boat is obvious. Michael's boat is rowed ashore, hallelujah. What kind of boat is yours? What is the context?

Comment: In saying "a boat/ship", the OP makes it clear that he looks for a generic term. Barrie has seen the point, too.

Comment: You can also _run_ it, but only [aground](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+aground).

Comment: @terdon: You can also _run_ a sailboat [downwind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_sail#Running_downwind), but not upwind (that'd be _beating_) or sideways to the wind (_reaching_).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen thanks, I've always called that running _before_ the wind, hadn't heard _running downwind_.

Answer (score 22):

You *pilot* it. And on larger watercraft having an enclosed room containing the *pilot’s wheel*, that room is called the *pilot house*.

The verb was either borrowed from *pilot* (n.) or from the French *piloter*, according to *Online Etymology Dictionary*:

> *pilot* (v.) 1640s, “to guide, lead”; 1690s, “to conduct as a pilot”, from *pilot* (n.) or from French *piloter*.
>
> *pilot* (n.) 1510s, “one who steers a ship”, from Middle French *pillote* (16c.), from Italian *piloto*, supposed to be an alteration of Old Italian *pedoto*, which usually is said to be from Medieval Greek *pedotes* “rudder, helmsman”, from Greek *pedon* “steering oar”, related to *pous* (genitive *podos*) “foot”.

As others have pointed out, *pilot* (v.) has also acquired a specialized modern sense (“to lead a ship *through a difficult or dangerous area of water*”, *Macmillan Dictionary*) and *pilot* (n.) now generally means such a specialist. But the general sense of steering a ship is still in use today, just as it was in the 19c and 20c. This explains how the terms were borrowed by balloonists and airmen when those technologies came on the scene.

Comment: The pilot, however, is oftentimes not at the helm (at least on a larger ship). Really, as has been mentioned, this question needs a bit more specificity.

Comment: I always thik of the _pilot_ as the one who knows how to navigate through tricky passages but is not necessarily at the helm, as in [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pilot) definition.

Comment: A ship's pilot is neither the captain nor the helmsman: I wonder why an aeroplane's pilot is both?

Comment: These comments refer to the noun; OP asked about the verb. The noun "pilot" often refers to a profession in the maritime context, but can also refer to the person at the helm. The verb refers to the act of guiding or steering the ship.

Comment: @TimLymington It is untrue that the maritime pilot is neither the captain nor the helmsman. It depends on the situation and the size of the craft (and the crew). They can often be the same person. A licensed captain is a trained pilot; the captain or the pilot may well take the helm.

Comment: Possibly national differences: in British waters, a *pilot* is specifically qualified on one stretch of water, and a skipper who called himself a pilot merely because of his captain's ticket would be in trouble or (in some circumstances) in jail. Similarly, though pilots give helm instructions, they virtually never actually steer, largely for insurance reasons.

Comment: A "pilot" is specialist for one body of water in the US as well.

Answer (score 14):

If it’s a sailing boat, you sail it. If you’re the captain of a ship, you skipper it, and if you’re the helmsman, you steer or helm it, but otherwise, there’s no general term. I did once hear a former captain of the Royal Navy aircraft carrier ‘Ark Royal’ say that he drove it, but that was in jest.

Comment: Isn't the helmsman the one at the wheel? According to M-W, they are 'the person at the helm'. There may be a job title usage too, but coupling the sense given here by M-W with most definitions' statement that 'a helmsman is a person who _steers_ the ship etc', the person at the wheel _steers_ the ship. // Skipper is defined as 'act as the skipper of'.

Answer (score 6):

> ### navigate
>
> *v.tr.*
>
> 1. To control the course of a ship or aircraft. To plan, direct, or plot the path or position of (a ship, an aircraft, etc.). To act as the navigator in a car, plane, or vessel and plan, direct, plot the path and position of the conveyance.
> 2. To voyage over water in a boat or ship. To travel over, through, or on (water, air, or land) in a boat, aircraft, etc. sail. To move on, over, or through (water, air, or land), esp. in a ship or aircraft. To travel on water propelled by wind or by other means.
>
> *v.intr.*
>
> *Rare* to voyage in a ship; sail.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/navigate

Answer (score 2):

You can say either *row* or *propel*. You can also *paddle* a boat.

Answer (score 1):

The case with the boat would greatly rely on the boat you use or refer to. But "rowing" is more commonly used.

Comment: Pretty sure you don't row a speedboat.

Answer (score -1):

You 'steer' a boat especially if it is not a paddle boat

Comment: This is too simplistic, especially in light of the top two answers already discussing it. *Steering* implies, well, steering. You can steer a car or a motorcycle, too, but the OP is not asking for an equivalent of that.

Comment: @RegDwigнt But can't you also pilot a car, a motorcycle, or a plane?

Comment: @RegDwight Look at the AHDEL, Collins definitions for 'helmsman'.