# What is the equivalent word for "flight" when riding a boat instead?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, vocabulary, analogy

Example: My "flight" is at 2:00 PM.

I am a Filipino, and English is our second language here in the Philippines. We have 7,000+ islands here and travel by boat is very common, yet we don't have an equivalent word for "flight", even in our language. We jokingly just say, "What time is your **float**?"

---

I think "voyage" as suggested below is the most fitting. Thank you!

Comment: suggest [boards.cruisecritic.com](http://boards.cruisecritic.com/showthread.php?t=1971866). Please show work you've done to try to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127034/if-i-drive-a-car-and-ride-a-motorcycle-what-do-i-do-with-a-boat

Comment: You're assuming there _is_ one. It doesn't work for a rail or bus journey: 'My train / bus is / leaves at 2 pm'. The usual way of expressing this is 'We sail at 2 pm'.

Comment: How about "launch"?

Comment: @Edwin: Nothing wrong with [My train is at seven](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22my+train+is+at+seven%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), [My bus is at nine](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22my+bus+is+at+nine%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), etc.

Comment: If you travel on a flight, your flight is at 2 PM. If you travel on a boat, your boat is at 2 PM. I fail to see what the difficulty here is.

Comment: You can say "My plane is at 2 pm" also.

Comment: This question cannot be answered only by commonly-available references and it is a good question. There are colloquial usages also and you can see that there are details based on the answers.

Comment: @FF ... As I said. I'm not going to accept that the nouns 'flight' and 'train' are _equivalent_.

Comment: "Gentlemen to bed, for tomorrow we rise at dawn, and breakfast at 8:30 for 9, that we may embark on our little boat trip at 10-ish."

Comment: Exactly as Edwin says, it's silly to see "flight" and "train" as equivalent.

Comment: It's called a 'cruise' if you're on a large boat. Otherwise, 'boat-ride' is fine.

Comment: @Joe Why is that silly? They _are_ perfectly equivalent. When you say, “My flight is at 2”, you're not talking about the journey through the air, you're talking about the vessel, the plane. This is just as with all other means of transportation: you don't say, “My bus ride is at 2”, but “My bus is at 2”. _Is_ here simply denotes _leaves (according to the time table)_. Obviously, the whole flight isn't at 2. It might be from 2 till 4:30, but it isn't _at_ any particular time.

Comment: The return flight was much smoother. */??The return bus / train / ferry /  was much smoother. ///The flight was not without its dramas. /// Though the company only had three planes, it managed ten flights to Tropicali Island that Tuesday. Here we have a title where OP's example is considered to narrow the goalposts; he doesn't clarify whether this is his intention. But the usages of 'flight' and 'cruise', 'bus', etc only overlap in specific areas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know about your flight but my *cruise* starts at 2 pm.

Other than cruise, you may also use "voyage" or "sail" to mean a trip by boat or ship.

Comment: To me, "cruise" is a bit limited. I would only use it in certain situations like pleasure-trips or patrols where the purpose of the trip is something other than to get from A to B.

Answer (score 11):

**Sailing**, or **boat-trip**.

You could use "voyage" or "journey" too but I am assuming from your analogy with "flight" that you're looking for something that can *only* be used in relation to boats.

Comment: As someone who lives in English-speaking ferry-boat country, "sailing" is the noun with *overwhelming* currency.

Comment: I definitely think "voyage" has nautical/space connotations. It doesn't seem valid for car, train, or plane journeys, and most people will probably not assume you mean a space-flight rather than a boat-ride. This may be subjective, but "set sail on a voyage" or even "take off on a voyage" implies a boat to me. The relationship with space is probably to do with the sense of exploration both involve.

Comment: I definitely favor *voyage* for this, it's the right word for a trip by boat.  *Sail* could be used for a trip by sailboat only, and I would never use *sailing* for the trip, it's the action, analogous to *piloting* or *driving*.

Comment: @Magus Space is traditionally traversed with ships, so there's a lot of terminology overlap there.  An airship could have a voyage, I suppose, but planes aren't usually called airships.

Comment: @Brilliand: Yeah, that too. That was what I was trying to say. But I expect that part of the reason we call them space *ships* is some romantic connection in the minds of people imagining them to exploring the seas, rather than just transportation.

Comment: a "voyage" is what odysseus did. a "flight" ("flight AF13") is exactly a "cruise" ("cruise AF13")

Answer (score 6):

It's not *exactly* the same, but you could say something like:

> I **set sail** at 2:00 PM.
>
> We will **set sail** at 2:00 PM.

Comment: The question indicates that the asker is requesting an equivalent to the _noun_ "flight", not the verb (see the given example: "My 'flight' is at 2:00 pm").

Comment: The sailing is at 2:00 PM? Unfortunately, most nautical terms are verb phrases, not nouns (set sail, cast off, weigh anchor). Depending on the trip purpose, duration, size of vessel, etc., a number of different terms could be used. A week on an 80,000 tonne luxury ship going from NYC to Antigua would be a _cruise_, while 20 minutes on a ferry would be a _trip_, and an hour in a runabout taking in the sights might be a _ride_.

Comment: **set sail** is equivalent to take off.  PHIL, EXCELLENT -- for shorter than cruise, "trip" or "ride".

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in your title, the word corresponding to *flight* is *passage*. In the text of your question, it seems that you are concerned with the time of departure. In this case, *leaves* or *departs* apply equally well to all forms of public transport---by land, sea, or air.

Comment: passage is something else.  ask any travel agent, the equivalent of "flight" is "cruise" (on a cruise-ship; for container ships, I simply don't know)

Comment: @Joe Blow: I'm assuming that the aim is to get from A to B, as with a flight. Admittedly, very few people nowadays choose sea travel for this purpose. A cruise is a circular trip which is an end in itself, not a means. It has no equivalent in air travel.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard "My [launch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/launch) is at 2:00pm."

Comment: that is the equivalent of **take-off**.  How hard is this guys, geesh

Answer (score 2):

If it's a relatively short scheduled ferry service, you can use **crossing**.

"Are you on the 1pm or the 3pm crossing today?"

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is *[navigation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/navigation)* in general sense. (for answering the question title)

> Travel or traffic by vessels, especially commercial shipping.

But in colloquial speech, you *cannot* say "My navigation is at 2:00pm."

In your example, you mean the "scheduled time" sense of the word. In my opinion, there is not a specific word that covers all scheduled times of all water travels that can substitute "flight" in your example.

One of the answers mentioned *sailing*, which has a dictionary definition in this sense but it does not sound right when you say "My sailing is at 2:00 pm".

You would use general words or rephrase what you want to say. For example, you can use *departure*.

> My departure is at 2:00 pm

Just to be more specific, you might say "departure from the seaport". Though not all water travels start from a seaport.

Comment: The main problem with this answer is not it's wonderful amount of detail, but the eventual conclusion that a manner of conveyance is equivalent to a launch. Many others make the mistake of supplying a means of conveyance. This could be improved, but is better than many.

Comment: My conclusion is there is not an exact equivalent. But I can consider your suggestions about how to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You could say

> My ship weighs anchor at 2:00 pm.

And unlike the phrase *set sail*, the phrase *weigh anchor* can apply to ships that don't have sails.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weigh_anchor

Comment: weighs anchor is equivalent to **take off**, not **flight**.

Answer (score 1):

It's astounding this is so complicated.  And it's astounding so many people don't realise he's looking for a word that fits in the same sentence, or confirmation there is no such word.

airplane/flight/takeoff

boat/cruise/departure

HOWEVER cruises take weeks/month whereas flights take minutes/hours.

the closest equivalent (in a sense) to "my flight is at 3PM: is "my cruise is on wednesday".  it's usually a little weird to say "my cruise is at 3PM", exactly as it would be a little weird to say "my flight is at 3:13:37.45 seconds"

For more clarity on the three "things" above

airplane 'Spirit' / flight AF011 / takeoff 14:45

boat 'QE2' / cruise 'SunnyMed17B' / departure 10:00

the simple answer to your literal question is, of course, "my cruise is at 2PM". But bear in mind the "timescale metric weirdness" mentioned here.

note that you can say "my flight leaves at.." just as you can say "my cruise leaves at.."

Answer (score 0):

1. **[embark](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=embark&allowed_in_frame=0)** (v.) Look up embark at Dictionary.com
   1540s, from Middle French embarquer, from em- (see en- (1)) + barque "small ship" (see bark (n.)). Related: Embarked; embarking.
2. **journey** |ˈjərnē| noun (pl. journeys)
   an act of traveling from one place to another: she went on a long journey.
3. If you go on a cruise ship however. Your [cruise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruise) will start.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: @medica Actually, *embark*, while a verb form is sort of on point.

Comment: @bib - "My "flight" is at 2:00 PM." /= "I'm embarking on a journey."

Comment: @medica Yes, but "my embarkation [or *embarcation*]" is.

Comment: @bib - honestly. I (AmE) would never say "my embarcation." I would simply say *my ship departs at 2:00 PM. I need to be abourd by 12."

Comment: @medica That's why I didn't offer it as an answer.

Comment: @bib: Even that isn't really valid. I assume OP would also use flight in the sense he means in the sentence, "I had a nice flight." I doubt there is anyone who would say "I had a nice embarkation." Overall, this answer isn't right at all. Journey has no connotations at all of the method of transport, and cruise has been offered by others. Embark is as bad as depart in that it only means the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

While it isn't just one word, the common expression I have heard amongst my sailor friends for departure is *"set sail"*.

"We set sail at 2:00pm."

For the overall trip, *voyage* seems to be the preferred, at least amongst my crew.

HTH.

Comment: set sail is equivalent to take off, not flight